# How to unit test mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, sinon

So I tried to find this out on my own for the whole day. I've found some tips, but that's not enough.

I want make a query and manipulate with it's result. Problem is, the library I've used doesn't allow for that, as it returns a string, or object format. It doesn't simulate the result. Or at least I couldn't achieve it that way.

my code:

• controller:

```
  const UserMock = sinon.mock(User)
  const expectedResult = {
      "_id" : "58cc67ab9b11ec4cfd9ebb6e",
      "email" : "test@email.com", 
      "password" : "$2a$10$3Oka.IuS/xoGJ4CgxWOPVerE.IVvKemsZchegvwsxopSwIJ08G1P."
    }

  UserMock
    .expects('findOne').withArgs({ email: 'test@email.com' })
    .chain('exec')
    .resolves(expectedResult)

  User.findByEmail('test@email.com')
    .then((user) => user.comparePassword('password'))
    .then((user) => user.publishParse(user))
    .then((user) =>
    {
      UserMock.verify()
      UserMock.restore()
      assert.equal(user, {expectedResult.email, id: expectedResult._id})
      done()
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)
```

• model:

```
...

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    dropDups: true,
    minlength: [5],
    validate: {
      isAsync: true,
      validator: isEmail,
      message: 'Invalid email'
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: [6, "Password must has at least 6 chars."]
  }
}, {
  toJSON: {
    transform: function(doc, ret)
    {
      ret.id = ret._id
      delete ret._id
      delete ret.__v
    }
  }
})

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password)
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, (err, isMatch) =>
    {
      if (err || !isMatch)
      {
        return reject(err)
      }

      resolve(this)
    })
  })
}

userSchema.methods.publishParse = function()
{
  let _user = this.toJSON()
  delete _user.password
  return _user
}

userSchema.statics.findByEmail = function(email)
{
  return this.findOne({ email }).exec()
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
export default User
```

Libraries I used:

- mongoose
- mocha
- sinon
- sinon-mongoose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mockgoose](https://github.com/mockgoose/mockgoose) runs an in memory copy of MongoDB and once setup, patches mongoose so your app connections go to the test instance.

```
before(function() {
  return mockgoose.prepareStorage().then(()=>{
    return mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/whatever')
  })
})

after(function() {
  return mockgoose.helper.reset()
}}
```

Mockgoose saves all the "why isn't my mock like mongoose" time which only gets worse once you get past a simple example into multiple queries or more complex operations.

Although the tests aren't really unit tests at this stage, it's the best solution I've found for mongoose database interaction if you can live with the addition of `mongoose` and `mongodb` and `mongodb-prebuilt` to your "unit" of test.

The `monbodb-prebuilt` dependency is ~ 200MB so adding it can impact dev dependency install time.